403 Error when trying to access Colab Ollama server
I created a server that runs Ollama using ngrok and Google colab.
!pip install aiohttp pyngrok

import os
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

os.environ.update({'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/usr/lib64-nvidia'})

async def run(cmd):

    '''
    run is a helper function to run subcommands asynchronously.
    '''
    print('>>> starting', *cmd)
    p = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
      *cmd,
      stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
      stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
      )

async def pipe(lines):
    async for line in lines:
    print(line.strip().decode('utf-8'))

    await asyncio.gather(
        pipe(p.stdout),
        pipe(p.stderr),
        )

await asyncio.gather(
    run(['ollama', 'serve']),
    run(['ngrok', 'http', '--log', 'stderr', '11434', '--authtoken',      '2h8g2xEIRTbSaXraFIRdsdpbACT_6HnpzGYxvEUFcbYyWPhYo', '--host-header="localhost:11434"']),
)

I tried to connect to it using windows client.
the connection is fine but the problem is with the response, which the server always return a 403
error:
t=2024-05-29T23:40:22+0000 lvl=info msg="join connections" obj=join id=d124d435c3b1 l=127.0.0.1:11434 r=ip@ [GIN] 2024/05/29 - 23:40:22 | 403 |     295.834µs |   ip@ | HEAD     "/"
I looked for some solutions like changing OLLAMA_ORIGIN=""
but it didn't work
does Ollama serve requires some sort of authentication?

Under [Service] section of the .service file add:
Environment="OLLAMA_ORIGINS=*"

You mentioned OLLAMA_ORIGIN, but it is OLLAMA_ORIGINS and you set it as an empty string, but you need to set to "*".
Just add the code given below to set the OLLAMA_ORIGINS:
import os

# File path
file_path = '/etc/systemd/system/ollama.service'

# Read the existing file content
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Flag to check if [Service] section has been processed
in_service_section = False

# New content to be added
new_lines = []
environment_added = False

for line in lines:
    if line.strip() == '[Service]':
        in_service_section = True
        new_lines.append(line)
        continue

    if in_service_section and line.strip() == '':
        if not environment_added:
            new_lines.append('Environment="OLLAMA_ORIGINS=*"\n')
            environment_added = True

    new_lines.append(line)

# If [Service] section is not found or Environment variable is not added, add it
if not environment_added:
    new_lines.append('\n[Service]\n')
    new_lines.append('Environment="OLLAMA_ORIGINS=*"\n')

# Write the changes back to the file
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(new_lines)

print('Environment variable added successfully.')

Add the code just above the cell you shared and execute it, it will set the OLLAMA_ORIGINS value. Don't forget to set OLLAMA_HOST in Windows CLI at cmd:
set OLLAMA_HOST=<Link generated by ngrok>

